# Как отключить модуль K2 в Joomla

Tags: joomla

Здравствуйте. Как Как отключить модуль K2 в Joomla и можно ли будет его включить, так, чтобы ничего не сломалось?

Comment: K2 - это компонент, который имеет много модулей и плагинов... что вы хотите отключить?

Comment: ну понимаете, когда я подключил сайт на Joomla и зашёл в админ панель, то увидел такую админ панель https://yadi.sk/i/0ht6dMF73ERuJg. Я не понимаю, как настраивать сайт, если такая админ панель. Как сделать привычную, удобную Joomla админ панель? Как в этой админ панели зайти в "менеджер модулей"? Картинка админ панели доступна по сылки в виде картинки

Comment: данный сайт собран на готовом шаблоне, где подключены Virtuemart и К2, если вы отключите (удалите К2) у вас сайт рухнет, по крайней мере контентная часть, если вы  не знакомы с данным функционалом - лучше не трогайте. Просто написать что вам делать - не получится, это очень долгая история.....

Comment: а как тогда перейти в "менеджер модулей"? и как включить нужны мне модуль?

Comment: Возможно вам дали доступы к админке - как редактору! , т.е работник который добавляет некий контент.... в данном случае вы не имеете доступа к стандартным функциям админки, уточните это у тех кто вам дал доступы.

Comment: мне дали только исходники, честно говоря